# Simple MVVM binding issue

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, mvvm

I have one textbox and one button. The Button Command should change the property which is binded to the TextBox.

But I don't see any visual changes after command execution.
I think it easy question related to wpf binding

Please help me with this issue

**Source of app:**

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:SampleViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Height="23" Width="120" Text="{Binding MyName}"  />
        <Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
Private _myName As String
Public Property MyName As String
  Get
    Return _myName
  End Get
  Set(value As String)
    _myName = value
      OnPropertyChanged("MyName")
  End Set
End Property

Public _buttonCommand As DelegateCommand
Public ReadOnly Property ButtonCommand As DelegateCommand
Get
  Return If(_buttonCommand IsNot Nothing, _buttonCommand, 
  New DelegateCommand(AddressOf Execute, AddressOf CanExecute))
End Get
End Property

Private Sub Execute()
  MyName = "Executed"
End Sub

Private Function CanExecute() As Boolean
  Return True
End Function

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler
Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
  RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint in Execute()?

Comment: could you try to set a breakpoint at `Execute` and see whether it;s executed at all?

Comment: Doesn't MyName need to be Observable?

Comment: Can you show me example of Observable property?

Comment: @Garrett: I am not able to reproduce this issue. Is this a cut down version of your actual code?

Comment: @sixlettervariables : I'm also unable to reproduce the issue. I guess there is something wrong elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1.
    Class MainWindow
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

2 . In Public Sub New() make sure you write `Me.DataContext = Me` to set the DataContext

**Note**: Ignore step 2 if you're using a ViewModel and setting it in XAML

3 . Modify the ProperyChanged like this:
        `Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`

Only after [implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) will the Binding correctly refresh the MyName property after the PropertyChanged event

Comment: His code does NOT work and I was able to reproduce his problem on VS 2010. The following fixed the problem  on my computer.

Comment: I can't reproduce his issue with his VB and XAML (VS12). I wonder if he omitted "Implements INotifyPropertyChanged" from the class declaration. It is the only part of the code I assumed he did. I've removed my downvote under the assumption the OP left out the INPC header code.

Comment: I agree that changing the DataContext is unnecessary when he is using a ViewModel and setting it in XAML. Since he did not mention if he implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, I gave a full detail on how to fix the problem with CodeBehind. I'll note that in the answer

Comment: I found a problem part:
I've used a SimpleMVVM framework and ViewModelBase as base class for my viewmodel.
After implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged interface all work fine.
Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that works with your exact XAML (I took the DelegateCommand implementation from http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html ) Sorry it's C#, i'm really not into VB :D

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute,
                   Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public virtual void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

public class SampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public DelegateCommand _buttonCommand;
    public DelegateCommand ButtonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_buttonCommand == null)
            {
                _buttonCommand = new DelegateCommand(Execute);
            }
            return _buttonCommand;
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object o)
    {
        MyName = "executed";
    }

    public string MyName { get { return _myName; } set { _myName = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyName"); } }

    private string _myName;
}
```